# Angular js resource call to get json data in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

Created factory that will return json data and calling it from controller, but it is coming empty.
don't know where I made mistake.
no **console** error and in **network** json is also loading.

```
    'use strict';
var app = angular.module('angularJson', ['ngResource']);

    app.factory('loadJsonService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return {
            getData: function () {
                return $resource('json/productDetails.json');
            }
        };
    }])

  app.controller('angularJsonCtrl',['$scope', 'loadJsonService',function($scope, loadJsonService){

    $scope.loadProducts = function(noOfData){
        $scope.productDetails = [];
        $scope.productDetails = loadJsonService.getData().query();
    }

  }]);
```

Comment: Your request is async.  There's nothing to return because it hasn't finished yet.  You need to use promises.

Comment: You need to take a look at [ngResource Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put wait till request gets completed & there after you need to use `.$promise.then` over `$resource.query` function call. So that you could put function which will get call on success of API call.

```
loadJsonService.getData().query().$promise.then(function(res){ //success function
   $scope.productDetails = res;
}, function(error){ //error function
   console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: What is the utility of .$promise ? I always do .then() directly.

Comment: @sylvain1264 as far as I know, `$promise` return original server interaction promise.. If you directly `.then` over it, It might get resolved before data returned from server

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar

Comment: @ManojGupta Glad to help you, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must in getData function set $http request like this

```
$http.jsonp("json/productDetails.json")
        .success(function(response) {
          callback(response);
        });
```

Comment: may be use $http instead $resourse?

Comment: no man.. $resource is much matured & efficient than $http service,$resource play good with API calls

Answer (score 0):

Try built in `query` method. 
If you want to write your own get method do the following,

```
{
   method: 'GET',
   params: {
   key: value
},
isArray: true,
cache: true // if you want to cache
}
```